# how to work on a task while remaining threads finish working

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

Suppose I have an OpenMP 2.0 for loop that runs some operation:

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static)
for (int i = 0; i < lim; ++i)
{
  // do something thread-safe
}
threadSafeFunc();

unSafeFunc();
```

The functor `threadSafeFunc` is completely thread-safe so rather than running it serially after all those iterations are finished, I would like to get the first thread that finishes its allocation of tasks from the OpenMP loop to start working on it, and then for all threads to wait before executing `unSafeFunc` in serial.

How do I do this?

Comment: @JerryCoffin I'm surprised to hear that. I would have thought this would be a relatively common use case.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Can you motivate the previous statement? The latest standard seems to support many more things than simple loop constructs...

Comment: @Massimiliano: Okay -- I'm happy to retract my statements (and, looking at your answer, also quite happy to have been proven wrong).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be a solution to your particular issue:

```
#pragma omp parallel 
{ // #1
  #pragma omp for schedule(static) nowait
  for (int i = 0; i < lim; ++i) // #2
  {
    // do something thread-safe
  } // No implied barrier bue to the nowait clause
  #pragma omp single
  { // #3
    threadSafeFunc();
  } // Implied barrier
} // End of parallel region
unSafeFunc();
```

The idea is quite simple: you first open a `parallel` region in `#1`. Inside this parallel region you use two worksharing constructs:

1. a loop construct at `#2`
2. a single construct at `#3`

The loop construct (section 2.7.1 of the [standard](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/OpenMP4.0.0.pdf)) has a `nowait` clause that removes the implicit barrier at the end of the loop. Then the `single` construct (section 2.7.3):

> ... specifies that the associated structured block is executed by only
>   one of the threads in the team (not necessarily the master thread), in
>   the context of its implicit task. The other threads in the team, which
>   do not execute the block, wait at an implicit barrier at the end of
>   the **single** ...

The combination of the two constructs ensures that the first thread finishing its work in the loop will enter the `single` construct and execute `threadSafeFunc()`. Then all the threads will synchronize at the implied barrier and join with the `master` thread. At this point only the `master` thread will proceed and execute `unSafeFunc()`.